# "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was working on creation of a form for registration and here is my view file

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<fieldset>
<legend>Registration</legend>
    <div class="reg_form">  
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="reg_form">  
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="reg_form">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="reg_form">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
        <%= f.submit%>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
<hr>
User list <br />
<%= if!@users.blank? %>
<% for item in @users %> <br />
<%= item.first_name %> <br />
<%= item.last_name %> <br />
<%= item.email %> <br />
<%= item.password %> <br />
<% end %>
```

and the controller is as follows

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

layout "register"

def new
@user = User.new
@users = User.find(:all)
end

def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
redirect_to new_user_path
end
end

end
```

and the model file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

When I try to run this on server I get an error 
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
on line 1

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Why have you got both `@user = User.new
@user = User.find(:all)`?  Doesn't look like you should have `@user = User.find(:all)` in your new action at all

Comment: @Baloo ok I tried to display all users below the registration form in the view so I used User.find(:all). Do you think that leads to the mentioned error?

Comment: Yes, because you called both @user change it to `@users = User.find(:all)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `new` action as

```
def user        ### As your routes refer to user action and not new
 @user = User.new
 @users = User.find(:all) ### Note variable name is different
end
```

You can use `@users` instance variable to display list of users.

`@user` would refer to the new user that you are trying to create and pass it as an argument to `form_for`.

First problem in your code was that you were using the same instance variable for both cases as `@user`(they should be different) which was causing `@user` to be set as the value returned by `User.find(:all)`. 
Looking at the error, I can guess that you don't have any users in database currently so,
`User.find(:all)` returned `nil`. 
And in `form_for` you pass `@user` and get the error.

Also, remove `new` and `create` from the `User` Model.

**EDIT**

Your routes are configured differently. You have a route `UsersController#user` with `user` action which is rendering the view instead of `new`. In that case you should rename `new` action to `user` as currently `new` action is not being called.

I would advice you to go for a `RESTful` controller with the 7 specific actions. Refer to [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) to get a better idea.

Comment: I updated new action and still the error is shown. I have no clue of where I am doing it wrong

Comment: Could you please share the updated `new` action? And are you getting the same error?

Comment: Did you change `@user = User.find(:all)` to `@users = User.find(:all)`? Notice pluralized `@users`.

Comment: Yes I did make '@user' to '@users' and code in the question is updated.

Comment: @Krishna remove `new` and `create` methods from the model `User`. They are supposed to be in controllers and you already have them in controller.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I did but still the same error at #1 of view

Comment: @Krishna please share the updated Model and server logs.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I updated the code and included serverlogs

Comment: @Krishna your routes are setup differently. You are not calling the `new` action. You are calling `user` action which is not present in the UsersController

Comment: I do have a user in the database and however after making changes as mentioned by you I get an error 

uninitialized constant UsersController on Submit

Comment: Controller name should be plural. Update your controller name as `UsersController` and file name as `users_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering the `UsersController#user` action, which does not have a definition in your controller.

In order to render that action properly, you need to add it to your controller

```
def user
  @user = User.new
  @users = User.find(:all)
end
```

You probably should be looking to use one of the conventional actions (new, edit, etc.), but if you are certain you want the route to be `/user/user` then you'll need the corresponding action to set up the instance variables in the controller.